# Formula to find angular bisector when DC's are given

Tags: geometry, 3d

If direction cosines of $AB = ( L_1 , M_1,N_1)$ and direction cosines  of $AC = (L_2,M_2,N_2)$ then direction ratio of bisector of $∠BAC$ are?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem

Comment: @S007 i know that,but we will just get BD:BC = c:b = 1:1 because AB and AC are DIRECTION COSINES

Comment: Then use the ratio 1:1

Comment: @S007 so what will be points of B and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As absolute position does not matter in this case, you can take $A=(0,0,0)$ so that $B = ( L_1 , M_1,N_1)$ and $C = (L_2,M_2,N_2)$. The angle bisector is then line $AD$, where $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$, and its direction ratio is
$$
(L_1+L_2):(M_1+M_2):(N_1+N_2).
$$

Comment: Can I know why absolute position does not matter in this case?

Comment: Because you are looking for directions.

Comment: You can include external angular bisector

Comment: External angle bisector is usually defined for a triangle, not for an angle.

Comment: ABC makes a triangle

Comment: The external angle bisector at $A$ is perpendicular to the internal bisector $AD$.